# Objective-C: How to get a dictionary within a dictionary?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

the structure of my data is as followed:

{Courses = ( { Course {...}, CourseTime ( {}, {} ), CoursesStudents ( {}, {} ) } ) }

Here in more detail:

```
{
Courses =     (
            {
        Course =             {
            color = 77a0a9;
            created = "2016-02-05 18:05:59";
            id = "56b4d677-1070-4a26-9fd1-28204e2e862d";
            modified = "2016-02-05 18:05:59";
            "term_id" = "56b3cb9f-9044-4a36-91fd-5dc74e2e862d";
            title = "---------Neuer Titel";
            "weighting_reportmark" = 40;
        };
        CourseTime =             (
                            {
                "course_id" = "56b4d677-1070-4a26-9fd1-28204e2e862d";
                created = "2016-02-05 18:08:09";
                day = 5;
                enddate = "2016-07-08";
                endtime = "12:00:00";
                id = "56b4d6f9-5c4c-4c70-a5de-2d2d4e2e862d";
                modified = "2016-02-23 16:14:33";
                repeating = 1;
                room = A320;
                startdate = "2016-02-04";
                starttime = "10:00:00";
            },
                            {
                "course_id" = "56b4d677-1070-4a26-9fd1-28204e2e862d";
                created = "2016-02-05 18:09:50";
                day = 4;
                enddate = "2016-07-08";
                endtime = "08:00:00";
                id = "56b4d75e-c948-494b-8622-2d2d4e2e862d";
                modified = "2016-02-20 14:12:30";
                repeating = 2;
                room = Aula;
                startdate = "2016-02-04";
                starttime = "07:00:00";
            },
                            {
                "course_id" = "56b4d677-1070-4a26-9fd1-28204e2e862d";
                created = "2016-02-09 08:40:56";
                day = 2;
                enddate = "2016-07-08";
                endtime = "12:30:00";
                id = "56b99808-82a8-46fc-a554-79844e2e862d";
                modified = "2016-02-20 14:12:20";
                repeating = 1;
                room = C14;
                startdate = "2016-02-04";
                starttime = "11:45:00";
            },
                            {
                "course_id" = "56b4d677-1070-4a26-9fd1-28204e2e862d";
                created = "2016-02-10 23:33:55";
                day = 6;
                enddate = "2016-07-08";
                endtime = "11:27:00";
                id = "56bbbad3-0974-48a5-a76a-63ec4e2e862d";
                modified = "2016-05-07 07:39:02";
                repeating = 1;
                room = "";
                startdate = "2016-02-04";
                starttime = "08:00:00";
            },
                            {
                "course_id" = "56b4d677-1070-4a26-9fd1-28204e2e862d";
                created = "2016-02-11 11:09:05";
                day = 7;
                enddate = "2016-07-08";
                endtime = "10:10:00";
                id = "56bc5dc1-6b38-4823-8363-05844e2e862d";
                modified = "2016-02-23 16:00:06";
                repeating = 1;
                room = "";
                startdate = "2016-02-04";
                starttime = "08:09:00";
            }
        );
        CoursesStudents =             (
                            {
                "course_id" = "56b4d677-1070-4a26-9fd1-28204e2e862d";
                created = "2016-02-05 20:59:10";
                id = "56b4ff0e-ab0c-4a9a-8dec-30a24e2e862d";
                modified = "2016-02-05 20:59:10";
                "student_id" = "56b4ff0e-a0f0-4627-b798-30a24e2e862d";
            },
                            {
                "course_id" = "56b4d677-1070-4a26-9fd1-28204e2e862d";
                created = "2016-03-08 12:50:40";
                id = "56debc90-1948-4d4e-b0c3-7b664e2e862d";
                modified = "2016-03-08 12:50:40";
                "student_id" = "56b98e0d-3890-434e-8de6-79844e2e862d";
            },
                            {
                "course_id" = "56b4d677-1070-4a26-9fd1-28204e2e862d";
                created = "2016-03-08 12:50:40";
                id = "56debc90-8280-40f6-a216-7b664e2e862d";
                modified = "2016-03-08 12:50:40";
                "student_id" = "56c49805-9334-49be-9e2f-591a4e2e862d";
            },
                            {
                "course_id" = "56b4d677-1070-4a26-9fd1-28204e2e862d";
                created = "2016-04-20 16:36:02";
                id = "571793d2-2168-4281-af19-3a254e2e862d";
                modified = "2016-04-20 16:36:02";
                "student_id" = "5700c1d3-5810-473f-b472-606a4e2e862d";
            },
                            {
                "course_id" = "56b4d677-1070-4a26-9fd1-28204e2e862d";
                created = "2016-04-20 16:36:02";
                id = "571793d2-329c-4e3d-8df1-3a254e2e862d";
                modified = "2016-04-20 16:36:02";
                "student_id" = "570891bb-037c-4dce-bf60-698a4e2e862d";
            },
                            {
                "course_id" = "56b4d677-1070-4a26-9fd1-28204e2e862d";
                created = "2016-04-20 16:36:02";
                id = "571793d2-35bc-479a-80bb-3a254e2e862d";
                modified = "2016-04-20 16:36:02";
                "student_id" = "570891ba-7598-4df4-b036-698a4e2e862d";
            },
                            {
                "course_id" = "56b4d677-1070-4a26-9fd1-28204e2e862d";
                created = "2016-04-20 16:36:02";
                id = "571793d2-39ec-4f47-b776-3a254e2e862d";
                modified = "2016-04-20 16:36:02";
                "student_id" = "5700c1d3-1608-4d4b-a13a-606a4e2e862d";
            },
                            {
                "course_id" = "56b4d677-1070-4a26-9fd1-28204e2e862d";
                created = "2016-04-20 16:36:02";
                id = "571793d2-3d4c-4888-b668-3a254e2e862d";
                modified = "2016-04-20 16:36:02";
                "student_id" = "570891bb-c5ac-4497-926f-698a4e2e862d";
            },
                            {
                "course_id" = "56b4d677-1070-4a26-9fd1-28204e2e862d";
                created = "2016-04-20 16:36:02";
                id = "571793d2-4560-4aee-9bee-3a254e2e862d";
                modified = "2016-04-20 16:36:02";
                "student_id" = "56c02afd-4b8c-4973-9971-05624e2e862d";
            },
                            {
                "course_id" = "56b4d677-1070-4a26-9fd1-28204e2e862d";
                created = "2016-04-20 16:36:02";
                id = "571793d2-5d08-4c95-9c4f-3a254e2e862d";
                modified = "2016-04-20 16:36:02";
                "student_id" = "570891bb-f45c-485f-bfef-698a4e2e862d";
            },
                            {
                "course_id" = "56b4d677-1070-4a26-9fd1-28204e2e862d";
                created = "2016-04-20 16:36:02";
                id = "571793d2-6194-4e49-a5f0-3a254e2e862d";
                modified = "2016-04-20 16:36:02";
                "student_id" = "570891bb-1fac-4cee-ac9c-698a4e2e862d";
            },
                            {
                "course_id" = "56b4d677-1070-4a26-9fd1-28204e2e862d";
                created = "2016-04-20 16:36:02";
                id = "571793d2-8b08-452c-bed4-3a254e2e862d";
                modified = "2016-04-20 16:36:02";
                "student_id" = "570891bb-0060-4b77-a403-698a4e2e862d";
            },
                            {
                "course_id" = "56b4d677-1070-4a26-9fd1-28204e2e862d";
                created = "2016-04-20 16:36:02";
                id = "571793d2-954c-4328-91d3-3a254e2e862d";
                modified = "2016-04-20 16:36:02";
                "student_id" = "570891bb-b998-47c0-aeef-698a4e2e862d";
            },
                            {
                "course_id" = "56b4d677-1070-4a26-9fd1-28204e2e862d";
                created = "2016-04-20 16:36:02";
                id = "571793d2-9720-4602-a204-3a254e2e862d";
                modified = "2016-04-20 16:36:02";
                "student_id" = "570891bb-c1e8-45a9-b9fc-698a4e2e862d";
            },
                            {
                "course_id" = "56b4d677-1070-4a26-9fd1-28204e2e862d";
                created = "2016-04-20 16:36:02";
                id = "571793d2-b7cc-41f4-9546-3a254e2e862d";
                modified = "2016-04-20 16:36:02";
                "student_id" = "56fa8442-3320-4bb4-9dd9-23514e2e862d";
            },
                            {
                "course_id" = "56b4d677-1070-4a26-9fd1-28204e2e862d";
                created = "2016-04-20 16:36:02";
                id = "571793d2-c38c-42d8-9ffd-3a254e2e862d";
                modified = "2016-04-20 16:36:02";
                "student_id" = "570891bb-efb8-4447-96bc-698a4e2e862d";
            },
                            {
                "course_id" = "56b4d677-1070-4a26-9fd1-28204e2e862d";
                created = "2016-04-20 16:36:02";
                id = "571793d2-c8d8-4af6-ac28-3a254e2e862d";
                modified = "2016-04-20 16:36:02";
                "student_id" = "56e3f4dd-8d38-4ad7-92e1-34374e2e862d";
            },
                            {
                "course_id" = "56b4d677-1070-4a26-9fd1-28204e2e862d";
                created = "2016-04-20 16:36:02";
                id = "571793d2-d828-4a55-8b64-3a254e2e862d";
                modified = "2016-04-20 16:36:02";
                "student_id" = "56fa38bf-9394-498d-a4b3-22174e2e862d";
            },
                            {
                "course_id" = "56b4d677-1070-4a26-9fd1-28204e2e862d";
                created = "2016-04-20 16:36:02";
                id = "571793d2-e7b0-4516-aef3-3a254e2e862d";
                modified = "2016-04-20 16:36:02";
                "student_id" = "570891ba-2728-406d-be39-698a4e2e862d";
            },
                            {
                "course_id" = "56b4d677-1070-4a26-9fd1-28204e2e862d";
                created = "2016-04-20 16:36:02";
                id = "571793d2-f1bc-48af-b56f-3a254e2e862d";
                modified = "2016-04-20 16:36:02";
                "student_id" = "570891bb-ae8c-4112-a455-698a4e2e862d";
            },
                            {
                "course_id" = "56b4d677-1070-4a26-9fd1-28204e2e862d";
                created = "2016-04-20 16:36:02";
                id = "571793d2-fa7c-486b-a2f9-3a254e2e862d";
                modified = "2016-04-20 16:36:02";
                "student_id" = "5700c1d3-6bd8-43dc-bbf7-606a4e2e862d";
            }
        );
    }
);
```

}

I'm trying to get the Course-Dict: Course {...}, but I don't know how to do this.
I had this line of code to get the first, upper dict:

```
[currentCourse updateDataWithDictionary:responseDict[@"Courses"]];
```

But I don't know how to get the sub-dict. I tried this:

```
[currentCourse updateDataWithDictionary:responseDict[@"Courses"]["@Course"]];
```

This doesn't work. What's the right way to get this sub-dictionary?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: The contents of `Courses` – as well as `CourseTime` - is an **array**. `()` -> array, `{}` -> dictionary. So it's at least `responseDict[@"Courses"][0][@"Course"][0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"key": @{@"subkey": @"value"}};
NSLog(@"%@", [dict valueForKeyPath:@"key.subkey"]);
```

Result:

`2016-12-12 14:13:52.478 solution[57:57] value`

Your case:

```
[currentCourse updateDataWithDictionary:[responseDict valueForKeyPath:@"Courses.Course"]];
```

But in your supplied structure dictionary key `Courses` is Array, so right way should be:

```
[currentCourse updateDataWithDictionary:responseDict[@"Courses"][0][@"Course"]];
```

Comment: The object in the question is not a dictionary in a dictionary.

Comment: @vadian yes you are right, question doesn't match specified data structure.